# Why did Windows 10 upgrade itself from Pro to Enterprise?

Tags: windows-10

One of my laptops automatically upgraded itself from Windows 10 Pro to Windows 10 Enterprise yesterday. It is a Lenovo device that originally came with a digital Windows 10 Pro license. The upgrade wasn't visible as it happened and cannot be explained by any work tasks I performed that day. I only noticed it afterwards once alerted by an audit tool.

[Quick googling](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-windows-10-edition-changed-all-the-sudden-to/ab605331-d5ed-4653-a068-a9adcceed013) reveals that this could be caused by a bug in Windows. However, in my case, Windows remains activated even with Enterprise edition. I've never purchased or owned any Enterprise licenses.

Licensingdiag returns ambiguous information:

```
<DiagReport>
<LicensingData>
  ...
  <ProductName>Windows 10 Enterprise</ProductName>   <- ENTERPRISE
  <ProcessorArchitecture>x64</ProcessorArchitecture>
  <EditionId>Professional</EditionId>                <- PRO
  ...
```

I know how to proceed in downgrading back to Windows 10 Pro. However, out of curiosity, any idea what could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what Enterprise tier your license is based on, the upgrade could have taken place to force install an update that otherwise wouldn't install on your Pro copy.

Microsoft has done in the past with Windows 7, where Ultimate copies would receive updates the other tiers couldn't, and that posed security problems, so versions would be temporary elevated so the update could install, then silently downgraded afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doubtful this could explain it, though. There aren't recent Windows Updates installed. Additionally, I'm not subscribed to an Enterprise tier. It's a consumer Windows 10 Pro license that came bundled with the hardware.

Comment: You don't have to be subscribed to an Enterprise tier for Windows to temporarily upgraded itsefl from Pro to Enterprise in order to install updates or upgrade, say BitLocker or some such service/program/functionality. Enterprise comes with a support programme that Pro can't offer in terms of long term support, so it's not a bad hand you've been dealt, all in all. Enterprise versions are usually related to business domains, though. When you installed Windows 10, did you create a local account, or did you attach it to an existing Microsoft or Office 365 account?

Comment: Okay, I see! If it's temporary, when should I expect it to revert to Pro? After two days and a handful of reboots, it's still Enterprise. Windows 10 was installed with a temporary local admin account which gets deleted automatically by group policy. It's a hybrid-joined machine (both AD and Azure AD). All users, including me, are subscribed to Office 365 Business Premium and the accounts are traditional AD accounts that are synchronized to Azure AD. No personal Microsoft accounts are involved.

Comment: The way you describe your machine, it's understandable why MS would "treat" it as an Enterprise PC and upgrade your version without telling you. Have you tried the method described in this article? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/51564-downgrade-windows-10-enterprise-windows-10-pro.html

Comment: I don't think that's how Windows licensing should work, though. I haven't tried to downgrade yet, and I'll probably keep it as it is. Firstly because it doesn't really matter, and secondly, to keep digging if I find more traces of what might have led to this :)